# Multilevel Loops with Database Queries

Tags: php, pdo

I feel dumb for asking. In PHP is there something better than just doing this? I'm specifically refencing the incremental $resultX and $rowX variables for each inner loop.

```
$sql = "";
$data = array();
$result = query($sql, $data);
if($result){
    if($result->rowCount() > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            //code - and now we need to get more data related to this record
            $sql = "";
            $data = array();
            $result2 = query($sql, $data);
            if($result2){
                if($result2->rowCount() > 0){
                    while($row2 = $result2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASCCOC)){
                        //more code
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Use JOINs.

Comment: There are many many many times when you can't just join 4-5 tables together and get the result you want. Especially if the sub query returns multiple records for each main query record.

Comment: You have plenty of unneeded code here. Yes, you can simplify it a lot.

Comment: So helpful. Also not what I asked.

Comment: Hi Wes. If the data is so complex as you say, using multiple SQL queries from PHP as you did can be the right approach, nothing wrong with that. If you need more help here, we could use more details about the structure of data and desired results.

Comment: My question is exactly about naming the $result and $row variables numerically within the loop. If we go 4-levels deep is it really the best thing to go $result1, $result2, #resut3, $result4?